# How to save a free text views query entered into an exposed filter by the user?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I would like to save the entered exposed filter text by the user possibly into its own content type. Would I have to look at the url path for this via $_GET vars?

Comment: I must admit - I have no idea what you are trying to ask. Downvote is not from me. Close->Unclear is.

Comment: I think I understand what the question is, but it's kinda broad, and sounds like a basic PHP/HTTP question, and at this stage, unrelated to Drupal. So I vote off-topic. But to try to be helpful, yes, you'd start by examining the contents of $_GET to find the exposed filter settings.

Comment: Lets try to make is simpler: User goes to Views, user enters a filter query. I would like to save the query that is entered. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and add an extra submit handler:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_callback';
```

In your callback function use [node_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7) to save the values you extracted from `$form_state['values'];`

Comment: Awesome! Thx! I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help :)